# Android LinearLayout width

Tags: android, css, android-layout

I've speechbubbles and in there are two TextViews. The first Textview is the message and the second is for the time of sended message.

The width of the layout from second textview is based on the width from the message to align the time to left or right. If the message to short the user can't see the time complete.

This is correct (if the message not to short):

```
Hello!
 00:00
```

This is if the message to short:

```
Hel
 00

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gravity"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="11dp"
        android:paddingLeft="9dp"
        android:background="@drawable/speechbubble" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/message"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/singleMessageTime"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/message" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Do you have a image to see better what you need?

Comment: sure [Screenshot](http://fs1.directupload.net/images/150327/v7pdbw64.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would need 3 nested linear layouts, I Think this should accomplish what you are trying to do.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/gravity"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:gravity="end"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_margin="5dip"
     android:paddingTop="8dp"
     android:paddingBottom="11dp"
     android:paddingLeft="9dp"
     android:background="@drawable/speechbubble">

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/message"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Hello!" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/singleMessageTime"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="00:00" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I've left and right speechbubbles. The text align to left or right with the speechbubble. If I use your code are textviews and speechbubbles only left.

Comment: Are you changing the layout gravity programmatically?

Comment: you can add you speechbubble drawable to the gravity layout. Changing the gravity for this layout should change the alignment from left to right.

Comment: Can I check the width of the message text and change the layout width from wrap_content example to 40 if the width under 40? I hope you can understand me with my bad english.

Comment: You can change the layout width by using: layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(newWidth, layout.getHeight()));

Comment: You need to change you code, because there is no longer a LinearLayout with android:id="@+id/container". I'm assuming this is where you are setting the speachbubbles to left or right. This should be set to the layout with android:id="@+id/gravity". I can't really help you without seeing the code.

Comment: Thank you! I put your code in the second listview and now its work perfect! Nice thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Just set minwidth or minEMS to the textview who is controlling size of whole layout

```html
 android:minWidth="40dp"
```

OR

```html
    android:minEms="3"
```